# c# : VSTO -> MS Office Apps loosing focus?

Tags: c#, vsto, colordialog

So, what is happening, that Im loosing the focus from the Excel App to the PowerPoint App ?

**UPDATE:**
Your answers are correct (+1 Point), however its my fault, for not explaining the complete problem (I thought it is much simple). 
So, the problem statement expands to : From a MS PowerPoint, I open MS Excel, from where I open the ColorDialog. So, the problem is to gain the IWin32Window owner (or its handle) of the calling Excel App.

I used a modified solution from  [How do you pass the owner window to Show() method overload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631491/how-do-you-pass-the-owner-window-to-show-method-overload) to find the IWin32Window owner, and it works.

However, even doing so, the focus goes back to the parent PowerPoint App.

So, what is happening, that Im loosing the focus from the Excel App to the PowerPoint App ?

Comment: do you have any focus stealing code? It's focused when I try it and this isn't something that you can easily achieve in code (`ColorDialog` has no `Focus()`)

Answer (score 1):

If you are launching the form from a different form, you should set that as the `Owner` of the `ColorDialog`:

```
if (dlg.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)  //"this" being the owner form
```