# MessageBox closing without user action

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, excel, .net-assembly

I have VB.NET solution targeting .NET 4.0 Client Profile that includes add-ins for Excel and PowerPoint.  There is a separate assembly for each, and a third assembly with code that is common to both.  So, the common assembly is a dependency of the other two.

Sometimes, but not predictably or reliably, when code in the ***common*** assembly opens a MessageBox, it is dismissed automatically without user input.  It seems as if the ***calling*** assembly (i.e. the Excel add-in) has seized back control of the UI from the common assembly (maybe something to do with threading?), or the calling assembly code just continues executing while the MessageBox is shown.

I have observed this behavior in various and completely separate parts of my solution, and cannot figure out what the problem is.  Again, this does not happen all the time, and I cannot reproduce the condition reliably.  I am testing this on Windows 8.1 in Office 2013.

Unfortunately, there really isn't any relevant code to post, except:

```
MessageBox.Show(...)
```

I am hoping someone can provide some insight into what may be happening here, and provide a fix.

**EDIT**

After incorporating Hans' suggestion below, my code is now:

```
MessageBox.Show(New WindowWrapper(handle), [Message], [Caption], MessageBoxButtons.OK, [Icon])
```

where handle [Integer] = Excel.Application.Hwnd and:

```
Public Class WindowWrapper
  Implements IWin32Window
  Private hwnd As IntPtr

  Public Sub New(handle As IntPtr)
    hwnd = handle
  End Sub
  Public Sub New(handle As Integer)
    hwnd = New IntPtr(handle)
  End Sub

  Public ReadOnly Property Handle As IntPtr Implements IWin32Window.Handle
    Get
      Return hwnd
    End Get
  End Property
End Class
```

Still having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
  MessageBox.Show(...)
```

That is not exactly a very helpful snippet.  All it does show is that you are not paying attention to the most crucial argument.  *Especially* so in an Office add-in, absolutely essential to use, hardest to use correctly.

It is the *owner* argument.

Very, very important.  A dialog *must* have an owner to operate correctly.  Microsoft made it far too easy to not specify it directly.  If you use an overload that doesn't have the *owner* argument then it goes looking for an owner by itself.  Which usually turns out well.  But you are not always going to like the one it finds, the less control you have over the UI, the least likely you are going to be happy.  An obvious problem in an Office add-in, it controls about squat.

It uses the window returned by GetActiveWindow().  You are not going to be happy if that happens to be a window created by the Office program that subsequently closes.  That will close the message box as well.  Keep in mind that a message box is modal but only suppresses user input.  It does not in any way stop a program from closing a window.

And yes, you'll never be happy when you call it on a worker thread.  GetActiveWindow() has thread-affinity, the active window is a per-thread property.  There will not be any other window so the desktop becomes the dialog owner.  No risk of it closing, but you'll have nasty Z-order problems.  Windows owned by any other thread, like the ones created by the Office program, will not be disabled.  Or in other words, the message box window very easily disappears behind the main window.  Not to be found again by the user, he has no cue to go looking for it.

You *must* specify an owner, do not take a shortcut.  An obvious choice is the main window of the Office app, like the one returned by the Application.Hwnd property in Excel.  Sample code to create the IWin32Window implementation [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631491/how-do-you-pass-the-owner-window-to-show-method-overload).

Comment: Thanks, Hans.  What is the "owner" argument?  It's not described in the documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tewzaxwc(v=vs.100).aspx.

Comment: Right, wrong overload.  Look to the left, note the ones that take an IWin32Window argument.

Comment: Got it.  Didn't even know about the owner argument.  I think this is the answer to my original question.  Now, I need to figure out how to create a IWin32Window argument (I looked at the original link you provided and could not make sense of the C# code in this context).  Any VB.NET examples of using MessageBox.Show() with the owner argument would be helpful (searched around a bit but have found nothing so far).

Comment: After looking very promising, this answer ultimately did not solve the problem, and I am still experiencing an issue with MessageBoxes being closed/dismissed/hidden without user interaction.

Comment: You cannot get more help without posting repro code.

Comment: And of course it is *utterly* pointless to post the code that I recommended when it does not solve the problem.  Jeez.

Comment: So, posting code that does not work is now discouraged on SO?  That would be a radical departure from precedent.  If you have any helpful suggestions, I welcome your comments.  This SO snobbery is unwelcome.